# how to guarantee responses are processed in the same order as requests

Tags: axios

In response to a click handler, i currently perform a:

```
axios.get("http://whatever.com/itemId").then(response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

theoretically, a user might click several times extremely quickly in succession. however, I need to process responses in the same order as the requests are made, and these responses are not always ordered.

Can anyone give any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Came up with the following, which seems to work well.  Maybe such a thing should be part of the library itself.  Hope others find it useful.

```
import axios from 'axios';

class OrderedAxios {  

  constructor() {
    this.promises = []
  }

  get(url) {
    var outsideResolve;
    var outsideReject;

    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      outsideResolve = resolve;
      outsideReject = reject;
    });

    promise.resolve = outsideResolve;
    promise.reject = outsideReject;

    this.promises.push(promise);

    axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
        promise.response = response;                
        this.processPromises();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        promise.error = error;
        this.processPromises();
      })         

    return promise;
  }  

  processPromises() {            
    let continueProcessing = false;
    do { 
      continueProcessing = false;
      if (this.promises.length) {
        let promise = this.promises[0];
        if (promise.response || promise.error) {
          this.promises.shift();
          if (promise.response) {
            promise.resolve(promise.response);
          } else {
            promise.reject(promise.error);
          }
          continueProcessing = true;
        }
      }
    } while (continueProcessing);      
  }
}

export default OrderedAxios;
```